# Two curves in one plot

Tags: diagrams, plot, legend

I have three vectors `f`, `min(D_{T_{f}})` and `max(D_{E_{f}})`. These vectors are as follows:

```
   f=[\begin{matrix} 11&15&19&23 \end{matrix}],

min(D_{T_{f}})=[\begin{matrix} 1&0.5&1.9&1.3 \end{matrix}],
max(D_{E_{f}})=[\begin{matrix} 2&.75&2.6&.5 \end{matrix}]
```

Is it possible to plot  `min(D_{T_{f}})` vs `f` and `max(D_{E_{f}})` vs `f`, both in one plot?
I have used Maple, but indices can not be shown in legend. Is it possible to use Maple and then write legend in `\Latex`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Starting point: http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/feature/pgfplotstable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most popular package for plotting is `pgfplots`, and while there are dozens of example around, here is yet another one.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotstableread{
f min max
11 1  2
15 0.5 0.75
19 1.9 2.6
23 1.3 0.5
}\fminmax
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=$f$,
  legend pos=north west
]
  \addplot table[x=f,y=min] {\fminmax};
  \addplot table[x=f,y=max] {\fminmax};

  \legend{$\min(D_{T_{f}})$,$\max(D_{E_{f}})$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```